# How to find the previous date in perl for a given date

Tags: perl, date, datetime

How to find the previous date for a given date as Aug 17 in perl. I am able to get the current date in perl by using the below code. Can some-one help me to find the previous date for a given date.

```
Given date as : Aug 17
Required Date as : Aug 16
#Reverting the Date for the respective TimeZone
my $timezone='london';
my ($dt, $Curr_Bus_Date,$Curr_day);
$dt = DateTime->now(time_zone => $timezone);
$Curr_mon=$dt->strftime('%b');
$Curr_date=$dt->strftime('%d');
$Curr_date=~s/^0/ /;
$Curr_dt="$Curr_mon $Curr_date ";
print "The curr date is $Curr_dt \n";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DateTime class has a `subtract()` method. It's [clearly documented](https://metacpan.org/module/DateTime#Math-Methods).

```
$ perl -MDateTime -E'say DateTime->now->subtract(days => 1)'
2012-08-16T10:31:25
```

You can also do it with Perl's standard (since 5.10) Time::Piece and Time::Seconds classes.

```
$ perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -E'$t = localtime; $t -= ONE_DAY; say $t'Thu Aug 16 11:37:37 2012
```

With both of those approaches you should bear in mind that subtracting one day from the current date won't always get you to the previous day.

Comment: Y it wont always get me the previous day? what do mean by above lines, pleaseee expalin

Comment: pauler, because of daylight saving time. Read the paragraphs *math on non-UTC time zones* and *date vs datetime math* in the documentation.

Comment: Because "subtracting one day" presumably means "subtracting 24 hours" and not all days are 24 hours long. Think about what happens when you switch to and from daylight saving time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Add_Delta_Days` method :

```
use Date::Calc qw(Add_Delta_Days);
($year, $month, $day) = Add_Delta_Days(2012,8,17,-1);
```

Regards,

Comment: This works when i manually type the date, i mean exact date in dd_Delta_Days(2012,8,17,-1); But when i replace this 2012-->$Curr_year.. 8--->$Curr_date & 17--->$Curr_mon
I get this error: Date::Calc::Add_Delta_Days(): not a valid date

Comment: If someone is already using DateTime, then please don't drag them back into the bad old ways that we used to do this in the last millennium :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Date::Manip](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.32/lib/Date/Manip.pod) and its [date calculation facilities](http://search.cpan.org/~sbeck/Date-Manip-6.32/lib/Date/Manip/Examples.pod#TO_ADD_AN_AMOUNT_OF_TIME_TO_A_DATE) ?

I'd really check out CPAN for such commonly required functions. There's a lot of mature powerful modules there.

Comment: If someone is already using DateTime, then please don't drag them back into the bad old ways that we used to do this in the last millennium :-)